# Auto Find and Replace Script in Google Sheets - Delete some certain cell content - global replace

Tags: replace, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, find

Many cell entry's in my sheet contain extraneous words that I want to delete. I need a script to find keywords within a single column (in this case "B") and delete them in order.  The goal is to make the cell entries shorter.

My keywords are "Epic Artifactory DIY", "Barn", "Planks", "Pack, "Coupon: WTXPXZP", "Coupon: FREESHIP50", "Coupon: SPRING10", and "Wall".

I found this script, but it will not work for me.

```
function fandr() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r=s.getDataRange();
  var vlst=r.getValues();
  var i,j,a,find,repl;
  find="abc";
  repl="xyz";
  for (i in vlst) {
    for (j in vlst[i]) {
      a=vlst[i][j];
      if (a==find) vlst[i][j]=repl;
    }
  }
  r.setValues(vlst);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing "abc" to one of your keywords, and "xyz" to what you want to replace it with?

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that gets the data in only one column, and replaces all the content with an empty string (deletes the words).  Replace words in one column of a Google Sheet.

```
function replaceInColumn() {
  var arrayWordsToFind,dataInColumn,dataAsString,newString,
      newData,outerArray,i,lastrow,L,sh,ss,tempArray,toFind;

  arrayWordsToFind = [
  "Epic Artifactory DIY", "Barn", "Planks", "Pack", 
    "Coupon: WTXPXZP", "Coupon: FREESHIP50", "Coupon: SPRING10", "Wall"
    ]

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sh = ss.getSheetByName("Your Sheet Name Here");
  lastrow = sh.getLastRow();//Get row number of last row

  //sh.getRange(start row, start column, number of Rows, number of Columns)
  dataInColumn = sh.getRange(2, 2, lastrow).getValues();

  dataAsString = dataInColumn.toString();//Convert 2D array to a string
  //Logger.log('dataAsString: ' + dataAsString)

  newString = dataAsString;

  L = arrayWordsToFind.length;//The number of words to find

  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {//Loop once for every word to find
    toFind = new RegExp(arrayWordsToFind[i], "g");//define new Reg Ex with word to find - replace globally
    newString = newString.replace(toFind,"");//Delete all found words
  }

  //Logger.log('newString: ' + newString)

  newData = newString.split(",");//Convert string to 1D array
  outerArray = [];

  L = newData.length;

  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
    //Logger.log('i: ' + i)
    //Logger.log('newData[i]: ' + newData[i])

    tempArray = [];//Reset
    tempArray.push(newData[i]);
    outerArray.push(tempArray);//Create a new 2D data array
  }

  sh.getRange(2, 2, outerArray.length).setValues(outerArray);
}
```

Key words: find replace column global

Answer (score 0):

This Google Script function will help you find and replace text across all cells in a particular column (B in this case).

```
function findReplace() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var column = 2;
  for (var d=0, l=data.length; d<l; d++) {
    if (data[d][column-1] === "find") {
      sheet.getRange(d+1, column).setValue("replace");
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I also like the better variable naming, however this only works for replacing a single value rather than the list OP wants to use.